# Laravel belongsTo nested or belongsTo through

Tags: php, laravel

country:street 1:N
city:street 1:N

```
class City extends Model
{

    public function country()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);
    }
}

class Street extends Model
{

    public function city()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(City::class);
    }

    public function country()
    {
        return ...
    }
}
```

I need to load just country relation, without city
Street::with('country')->where('id', $id)->first();
like

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "abbey road",
    "country": {
        "id": 2,
....
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `country()` relationship on your `Street` model, unless your `streets` table has a `country_id`. You can simply chain relationships:

```
$street = Street::with('city.country')->where('id', $id)->first();
```

That will return your `Street` model, with the associated `City` and `Country` loaded. You can access the `Country` via `$street->city->country`:

```
$street = Street::with('city.country')->where('id', $id)->first();
$country = $street->city->country; // `Country: {'id' => 2, 'name' => '...'}`
```

If you want to be able to access `$street->country`, you'll need an accessor:

```
class Street extends Model {
  public function getCountryAttribute(){ 
    return $this->city->country;
  }
}
```

Then, the shorthand can be used:

```
$street = Street::with('city.country')->where('id', $id)->first();
$country = $street->country; // `Country: {'id' => 2, 'name' => '...'}`
```

As far as I'm aware, there isn't a `belongsToThrough()` relationship in Laravel, but chaining relationships should suffice.

Comment: Thanks! accessor is good idea. BelongsToThrough() relation really doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can use hasOneThrough relationship for this

```
public function country()
{
    return $this->hasOneThrough(
        Country::class,
        City::class,
        'country_id', // Foreign key on cities table...
        'id', // Foreign key on owners table...
        'city_id', // Local key on streets table...
        'id' // Local key on city table...
    );
}
```